# BASH variable not populating

Tags: bash

Got it working, here is the code: https://github.com/MNFaust/Linux_Memory_Mining/blob/master/subScripts/gdb_mine.sh

THANK YOU!

I am working on a subscript that is being called in a program to grab data from Memory Addresses and I am trying to automate the Stack and Heap mem dumps with GDB. Everything is working except for the memory address variable calls. Can someone please let me know if they see where I am going wrong with this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#========================================
#GDB processes: Gaining data
#By: Joshua Faust
#========================================


echo '------------------------------'
echo 'Process ID Data Required:     '
echo '------------------------------'
echo -n "What is the PID you are inquiring about: "; read PID
awk '{print $1,$6}' /proc/$PID/maps > "${PID}_maps"

# Grab the heap memory address for the PID
heapAddress=`cat /proc/$PID/maps | grep heap | awk '{print $1}'` #Grab the HEAP address in memory
heapAddressRemove=${heapAddress/-/" 0x"} #reove the -, add 0x to denote a hex address for GDB
heapAddressFinal= echo "$heapAddressRemove" | awk '$0="0x"$0' #adds a 0x to the from of the mem address to denote a hex address
# Grab the stack memory address for the PID
stackAddress=`cat /proc/$PID/maps | grep stack | awk '{print $1}'` #Grab the     STASCK address in memory
stackAddressRemove=${stackAddress/-/" 0x"} #remove the - in the memory address for GDB
stackAddressFinal= echo "$stackAddressRemove" | awk '$0="0x"$0' # adds a 0x to the front of the memory address to denote a hex addess
clear #Clear data on screen


echo '---------------------------'
echo 'Starting Mining Processes  '
echo '---------------------------'
#
# Ask user if you would like to view the memory map segments of the processes they chose.
#
echo -n "Would you like to see PID $PID memory map? (y or n) "; read pidAnswer
if [ $pidAnswer == "y" ] || [ $pidAnswer == "Y" ]
    then
    echo
    cat "${PID}_maps"
    else
    echo 'continuing to GDB session...'
    echo
fi
#
# Start of the GDB session:
#
echo -n "Are you ready to start a GDB session on $PID? (y or n) "; read mineAnswer
if [ $mineAnswer == "y" ] || [ $mineAnswer == "Y" ]
    then
    echo '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    echo '                       Getting Register Information                             '
    echo ''
    echo 'To dump: dump [memory,binary,tekhex, verilog] FileLocation Memory Segment Range '
    echo 'To quit: quit'
    echo Heap Address: $heapAddressFinal
    echo Stack Address: $stackAddressFinal
    echo '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    echo
    echo -n 'Would you like to dump the stack or the heap? '; read dump
    if [ $dump == "heap" ] || [ $dump == "Heap" ]
            then
            gdb --pid $PID -ex 'dump memory HeapDump.hex $heapAddressFinal' # to add another command -ex command
            echo 'Data dumped to HeapDump.hex'
    elif [ $dump == "stack" ] || [ $dump == "Stack" ]
            then
            gdb --pid $PID -ex 'dump memory StackDump.hex $stackAddressFinal'
            echo 'Data dumped to StackDump.hex'
    fi
else
    echo
    echo 'closing program....'
    exit 1
fi
rm -rf PID.txt #remove the temp file created to hold the PID
```

Here is the output where I am having issues. When I echo and call the variable stackAddressFinal and heapAddressFinal, they do not populate on console. However, in a test script I build they do.

```
Are you ready to start a GDB session on 21505? (y or n) y
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                   Getting Register Information

To dump: dump [memory,binary,tekhex, verilog] FileLocation Memory Segment Range
To quit: quit
Heap Address:
Stack Address:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Would you like to dump the stack or the heap?
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add quotes, like heapAddressFinal=`echo "$heapAddressRemove" | awk '$0="0x"$0'`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay, got it! Thank you: here is the working script in case anyone wanted to see what I changed: https://github.com/MNFaust/Linux_Memory_Mining/blob/master/subScripts/gdb_mine.sh